# I need to understand what does the while data_list do in the program?

Tags: python

I am very new to programming. I come across a program to sort a list. I need to understand what does
while data_list: mean? I know if while n > 10, it will iterate till n is greater than 10 but what does while data_list mean in the below program? does it mean while True?? Sorry for asking this basic question. Can anyone help me?

```py
data_list = [24, 55, 78, 64, 25, 12, 22, 11, 1, 2, 44, 3, 122, 23, 34]

new_list = []

while data_list:
    minimum = data_list[0]
    for x in data_list:
        if x > minimum:
            minimum = x
    new_list.append(minimum)
    data_list.remove(minimum)

print(new_list)
```

Can anyone help me understand it?

Comment: It's equivalent to `while data_list != []:`, so it keeps iterating until it has removed all the elements of `data_list`.

Comment: A list is considered truthy when it's not empty.

Comment: Would it make matters clearer if you changed it to *while len(data_list) > 0:* ? Also, there are much better ways of sorting a list of integers in descending order

Answer (score 0):

In Python, empty lists are considered False while non-empty lists are considered as True. Basically, what your code is saying is... "While data_list isn't empty, the following code below is executed."

This is an implicit boolean condition.